# error while streaming audio mp3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa

while i am playing audio from server through AVPlayer, i am getting this error however my code is correct and it is working fine for local files but when i try to fetch remote server files to play then AVPlayer give me this error.

My Code is:-

```
_asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mplayer.tridentsoftech.com/Recordings/sun.mp3"] options:kNilOptions];

[_asset.resourceLoader setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

_item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:_asset];

_playerController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
_songPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:_item];
_playerController.player = _songPlayer;
_playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[_playerController.view sizeToFit];
_songPlayer.volume = 5.0;
_playerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
_playerController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
[_songPlayer.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[self addChildViewController:_playerController];
[self.view insertSubview:_playerController.view atIndex:0];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (object == _songPlayer.currentItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {

        if(_songPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusFailed)
        {
            [_songPlayer play];

            NSLog(@"%@",_songPlayer.currentItem.error);
        }
        else if (_songPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay)
        {
            [_songPlayer play];
        }
        else if (_songPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",_songPlayer.currentItem.error);

        }
    }
}
```

i get this error... please help.. i am unable to get any solution on stack overflow for this question,only i get that this is an apple bug.. but there should be some workaround there.

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11828 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x155d4cc60 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12847 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not supported., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this after initialising asset:

```
NSError *error = nil;
AVKeyValueStatus keyStatus = [_asset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];

if (keyStatus == AVKeyValueStatusFailed) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

This should reveal the reason behind the failure.

Initially, I got an error using you code just as it is, but after checking the loading error I figured out that what was causing the problem in my case was Apple's new App Transport Security from iOS 9.0 and up which allows connections only to servers which use TLS 1.2, and only https secure connections. I cannot generalise this, but as far as I have tried since iOS 9.0 I never succeeded in getting http requests to work.

There is a lazy solution to this (not recommended) or a specific one.

First solution: Go to application's info plist and add a key "App Transport Security Settings" which should automatically set the value to a dictionary type. Set YES to "Allow Arbitrary Loads" key in this dictionary. This way you allow all connections regardless of security. Apple does not recommend that as it increases risks, but it depends on your app.

[image]

Second solution (better one): In the same "App Transport Security Settings" dictionary in the info plist instead of adding "Allow Arbitrary Loads" key add "Exception Domains" key. This is how the dictionary for this key should look like:

[image]

This way you only add your specific server connection to exceptions list. Worked in my case, now I can stream your mp3 file just fine.

Hope this helps.